# Codekit not working with the Compass / Zurb Scss Compiler When I Upgraded to Mavericks with Ruby 2.0

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, osx-mavericks, codekit

CodeKit is giving me the error of

Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: illegal switch in RUBYOPT: -E (RuntimeError)

(This action was triggered by a change to _settings.scss)

It was working fine before the Upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. Go to the "Terminal" and type:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

And it's done!

Comment: I just tried this, still having the same problem :( Codekit is updated too

Comment: oh strange I had to switch the preferences from using codekit's SASS interpreter on and off a couple of times. Working now... ':)

Answer (score 1):

You have CodeKit set to use an external Compass compiler, but you're running that Compass compiler in the old version of Ruby from 10.8 (Ruby 1.8.7).

You need to make sure Compass is running on the new system-installed version of Ruby (2.0) in Mavericks. Once you do that, you'll be all set. If you're using RVM, you can switch it back to the system Ruby and then simply run `sudo gem install Compass` to have Compass installed in the standard location.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem just now. I installed compass again as Bryan suggested. After this it still didn't work, so I went into my preferences and saw that I previously had Codekit compiling from Compass at a user selected path. I switched this to "USe Codekit's internal Compass copmiler" and it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Go to the "Terminal" and type:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

If you see this error:

> *Gem::LoadError on line ["298"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb: Could not find 'zurb-foundation' ....*

You probably need to install zurb-foundation, type this:

```
sudo gem install zurb-foundation
```

Comment: Zurb's Foundation used (v 3.x)to require that you **not** run CodeKit such that it compiled Compass projects via its internal Compass Compiler; with Foundation 5 that requirement appears to have been alleviated.

Answer (score 0):

I just Changed my Compass Advanced settings back to internal compass compiler (recommended) and it worked.

[image]